# Storing unitialized object in array, then constructing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dont think this is possible in c# but ill post it anyway.

Given my code

```
Control ctrlA = null, ctrlB = null;
var ctrlCollection = new []{ctrlA, ctrlB};
for (int i = 0; i < ctrlCollection.length;i++)
ctrlCollection[i] = new Control();
```

Is it possible to to construct these two objects and have them referenced to their respective variables (`ctrlA` and `ctrlB`)? As it stands, ctrlA and ctrlB will still have null references.

Comment: Are you trying to _defer_ your object initialization?
If you are on .NET 4.0+ have a look at [Lazy Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not.  (at least, not unless you want to work with pointers or something)  Will this work for you?

```
var ctrlCollection = new Control[2];
for (int i = 0; i < ctrlCollection.Length; i++)
    ctrlCollection[i] = new Control();
Control ctrlA = ctrlCollection[0], ctrlB = ctrlCollection[1];
```

Comment: Beat me to it...I type too slow.

Comment: +1 Correct and provides a solution, too.  My answer doesn't even answer the question.  I should downvote myself.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. The collection only stores references to its content, in your case `ctrlA` and `ctrlB`. When the statement `ctrlCollection[i] = new Control();` is executed, this reference is replaced by another one.

`ctrlA` will still point to the original `ctrlA` reference (being null), `ctrlCollection[i]` points to a newly initialized `Control` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as explicitly defining the length of the array.  There's no need to add nulls to the array and then later overwrite null with a newly instantiated Control in the array item.

```
var ctrlCollection = new Control[2];
for (int i = 0; i < ctrlCollection.Length; i++)
    ctrlCollection[i] = new Control();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctrlCollection = new []{ctrlA, ctrlB}; 
for (int i = 0; i < ctrlCollection.length;i++) 
{
    ctrlCollection[i] = new Control();
} 
Control ctrlA = ctrlCollection[0];
Control ctrlB = ctrlCollection[1];
```

Can't imagine why you'd want to, but this should do what I think you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the size of you collection is fixed you can do this:

```
Control ctrlA, ctrlB;
var controls = new[] {
  ctrlA = new Control(),
  ctrlB = new Control()
};
```

This requires that the `Control` variables are declared in the same scope as the `Control` array is initialized.